# Exception has occurred. _TypeError (type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Widget') on ListView.builder

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, dart-null-safety

I am trying to get the snapshot of members from my fbbackend but suddenly I get this error. ****type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Widget'****
code:

```
ListView.builder(
                        itemCount:  null,
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          if (snapshot1.hasData) {
                            //what ever you want
                     String val = snapshot1.data?.get('members')[index];
                                   //HERE(In front of [index])  
//RangeError (RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..1: 2)
                            return Text(val);
                          } else {
                            return const LoadingScreen();
                          }
                        },
                        ),
```

[image: Try to get snapshot of array in "members"]

What should I do to fix this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73686742/12838877 , same solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to check if the snapshot is null or not null before using them

```
    ListView.builder(
                        itemCount:  null,
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          if (snapshot1.hasData) {
                            //what ever you want
                     String val = snapshot1.data?.get('members')[index];
                                     HERE(In front of [index])  
//RangeError (RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..1: 2)
                            return Text(val);
                          } else {
                            return const LoadingScreen();
                          }
                        },
                        ),
```

you can get the specific documentsnapshot like this

```
StreamBuilder(
  stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("groups")
   .doc(groupId).snapshots(),
    builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
    if (!snapshot.hasData) {
      return Text("Loading");
    }
    var userDocument = snapshot.data["members"];
    return ListView.builder(
    itemCount: userDocument.length,
      shrinkWrap: true,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Text(userDocument[index]);
             ),
      }
  );
```

Comment: Now it’s says `_TypeError (type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Widget')` any idea on that?

Comment: Just edited it. check it

Comment: One last thing. There’s a problem with the Range it says: `RangeError (RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..1: 2)` I tried to put [0] in the end but it still says the same

Comment: at what line error happen? why are you using two listview? the error is saying you are trying to access the element in the array while the array is empty

Comment: Uhh sorry I have update the code above now Its indicated at the front of [index] in this line `String val = snapshot1.data?.get('members')[index];`

Comment: Yeah it’s now updated

Comment: check it again. it updated

Comment: `_TypeError (type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String')` on "return Text(userDocument?["members"]);" line in front of userDocument?

Comment: share the firebase db structure image?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248112/discussion-between-itsphil-and-brook-yonas).

Comment: Yes I have provide the image above

Comment: check it in the chat

Comment: accept my answer. it will be useful for someone