# Null check operator used on a null value flutter on future builder

Tags: json, flutter, api, dart

Error: Exception caught by widgets library, Null check operator used on a null value
The relevant error-causing widget was
FutureBuilder<WorldStatsModel

```
This is the json code:

class WorldStatsModel 
{
  int? updated;
  int? cases;
  int? todayCases;
  int? deaths;
  int? todayDeaths;
  int? recovered;
  int? todayRecovered;
  int? active;
  int? critical;
  int? casesPerOneMillion;
  double? deathsPerOneMillion;
  int? tests;
  double? testsPerOneMillion;
  int? population;
  int? oneCasePerPeople;
  int? oneDeathPerPeople;
  int? oneTestPerPeople;
  double? activePerOneMillion;
  double? recoveredPerOneMillion;
  double? criticalPerOneMillion;
  int? affectedCountries;

  WorldStatsModel(
      {this.updated,
      this.cases,
      this.todayCases,
      this.deaths,
      this.todayDeaths,
      this.recovered,
      this.todayRecovered,
      this.active,
      this.critical,
      this.casesPerOneMillion,
      this.deathsPerOneMillion,
      this.tests,
      this.testsPerOneMillion,
      this.population,
      this.oneCasePerPeople,
      this.oneDeathPerPeople,
      this.oneTestPerPeople,
      this.activePerOneMillion,
      this.recoveredPerOneMillion,
      this.criticalPerOneMillion,
      this.affectedCountries});

  WorldStatsModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    updated = json['updated'];
    cases = json['cases'];
    todayCases = json['todayCases'];
    deaths = json['deaths'];
    todayDeaths = json['todayDeaths'];
    recovered = json['recovered'];
    todayRecovered = json['todayRecovered'];
    active = json['active'];
    critical = json['critical'];
    casesPerOneMillion = json['casesPerOneMillion'];
    deathsPerOneMillion = json['deathsPerOneMillion'];
    tests = json['tests'];
    testsPerOneMillion = json['testsPerOneMillion'];
    population = json['population'];
    oneCasePerPeople = json['oneCasePerPeople'];
    oneDeathPerPeople = json['oneDeathPerPeople'];
    oneTestPerPeople = json['oneTestPerPeople'];
    activePerOneMillion = json['activePerOneMillion'];
    recoveredPerOneMillion = json['recoveredPerOneMillion'];
    criticalPerOneMillion = json['criticalPerOneMillion'];
    affectedCountries = json['affectedCountries'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['updated'] = this.updated;
    data['cases'] = this.cases;
    data['todayCases'] = this.todayCases;
    data['deaths'] = this.deaths;
    data['todayDeaths'] = this.todayDeaths;
    data['recovered'] = this.recovered;
    data['todayRecovered'] = this.todayRecovered;
    data['active'] = this.active;
    data['critical'] = this.critical;
    data['casesPerOneMillion'] = this.casesPerOneMillion;
    data['deathsPerOneMillion'] = this.deathsPerOneMillion;
    data['tests'] = this.tests;
    data['testsPerOneMillion'] = this.testsPerOneMillion;
    data['population'] = this.population;
    data['oneCasePerPeople'] = this.oneCasePerPeople;
    data['oneDeathPerPeople'] = this.oneDeathPerPeople;
    data['oneTestPerPeople'] = this.oneTestPerPeople;
    data['activePerOneMillion'] = this.activePerOneMillion;
    data['recoveredPerOneMillion'] = this.recoveredPerOneMillion;
    data['criticalPerOneMillion'] = this.criticalPerOneMillion;
    data['affectedCountries'] = this.affectedCountries;
    return data;
  }
}
```

This is the future builder function where it is showing the error:

```
FutureBuilder(
              future: statsServices.fetchWorldStatesRecords(),
              builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<WorldStatsModel> snapshot) {
                if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                  return Column(
                    children: [
                      PieChart(
                        dataMap: {
                          'cases':
                              double.parse(snapshot.data!.cases.toString()),
                          'recovered': double.parse(
                              snapshot.data!.recovered.toString()),
                          'deaths': double.parse(
                              snapshot.data!.deaths.toString()),
                        },
                        chartValuesOptions: const ChartValuesOptions(
                            showChartValuesInPercentage: true),
                        chartRadius:
                            MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 3.2,
                        legendOptions: const LegendOptions(
                            legendPosition: LegendPosition.left),
                        animationDuration: const Duration(seconds: 3),
                        chartType: ChartType.ring,
                        colorList: colorlist,
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(
                        height: 15,
                      ),
                      Card(
                        child: Column(children: [
                          ReusableRow(
                              title: 'updated',
                              value: snapshot.data!.updated.toString()),
                          ReusableRow(
                              title: 'cases',
                              value: snapshot.data!.cases.toString()),
                          ReusableRow(
                              title: 'todayCases',
                              value: snapshot.data!.todayCases.toString()),
                          ReusableRow(
                              title: 'deaths',
                              value: snapshot.data!.deaths.toString()),
                          ReusableRow(
                              title: 'todayDeaths',
                              value: snapshot.data!.todayDeaths.toString()),
                          ReusableRow(
                              title: 'recovered',
                              value: snapshot.data!.recovered.toString()),
                          ReusableRow(
                              title: 'todayRecovered',
                              value:
                                  snapshot.data!.todayRecovered.toString()),
                          ReusableRow(
                              title: 'active',
                              value: snapshot.data!.active.toString()),
                          ReusableRow(
                              title: 'critical',
                              value: snapshot.data!.critical.toString()),
                          ReusableRow(
                              title: 'casesPerOneMillion',
                              value: snapshot.data!.casesPerOneMillion
                                  .toString()),
                          ReusableRow(
                              title: 'deathsPerOneMillion',
                              value: snapshot.data!.deathsPerOneMillion
                                  .toString()),
                          ReusableRow(
                              title: 'tests',
                              value: snapshot.data!.tests.toString()),
                          ReusableRow(
                              title: 'testsPerOneMillion',
                              value: snapshot.data!.testsPerOneMillion
                                  .toString()),
                          ReusableRow(
                              title: 'population',
                              value: snapshot.data!.population.toString()),
                          ReusableRow(
                              title: 'affectedCountries',
                              value: snapshot.data!.affectedCountries
                                  .toString()),
                          ReusableRow(
                              title: 'recoveredPerOneMillion',
                              value: snapshot.data!.recoveredPerOneMillion
                                  .toString()),
                        ]),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(
                        height: 20,
                      ),
                      GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => const CountryList(),
                              ));
                        },
                        child: Container(
                          height: 50,
                          width: 300,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: const Color(0xff1aa260),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                              boxShadow: const [
                                BoxShadow(
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                  blurRadius: 2,
                                )
                              ]),
                          child: const Center(
                            child: Text(
                              'Track Country',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 15,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  color: Colors.black),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(
                        height: 10,
                      ),
                    ],
                  );
                } else {
                  return Center(
                    child: SpinKitFadingCircle(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      size: 50,
                      controller: controller,
                    ),
                  );
                }
              }),
```

This is the class in which I have fetched the Api:

```
class StatsServices {
  Future<WorldStatsModel> fetchWorldStatesRecords() async {
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(AppUrl.worldstatsApi));

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var data = jsonDecode(response.body.toString());
      return WorldStatsModel.fromJson(data);
    } else {
      throw Exception('Error');
    }
  }
```

This is the separate class for the URL:

```
class AppUrl {
  static const String baseurl = 'https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/';
  static const String worldstatsApi = baseurl + 'all';
  static const String countrylist = baseurl + 'countries';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here your error

```
 if (!snapshot.hasData) {
```

you put `!` before snapshot.hasData ,that make the wrong logic. remove it.
like this

```
 if (snapshot.hasData) {
```

Comment: if I am removing the ''!" mark then the program is running the else condition which is the spin kit

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73686742/12838877

see this how to handle response stream

Answer (score 0):

**Error Explanation:** Bang operator(!) AKA Null check operator or Null aware operator, means in flutter, when you use this operator, you are completely sure that variable is not going to be null in any case.
Now whenever we encounter **Null check/aware operator used on a null value** There are two ways to resolve it peacefully -

1. Use **if** conditional to confirm that variable is not null
2. Use **null-aware** or **if-null** operator **??** like

```
  //1.
  if (foo != null) {
    String otherStr = foo;
    print(otherStr);
  }

  //2.
  String? foo;
  String str = foo ?? "dummy";
  print(str);
```

Since you provided partial error; based on provided base url when you hit `https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/updated`, we do not receive expected response hence your error is at `snapshot.data!`. So before using **`!`** make sure your variable is not `null`.

Comment: but its just not working..i don't know why..I guess I have to code it again..Thanks for the help though!

Comment: It'll be helpful if you attach complete error log.

Comment: It got solved after I did a couple of changes but the changes were not like they would make huge differences, then I run the program again it was working fine...I don't know how..lol.
I guess it might be a bug or I will check into what caused the error!!